# How to implement text recognition from an image using Tensorflow lite for Android App

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, text-recognition

How to implement text recognition from an image using Tensorflow lite for Android App. I didn't find in Tensorflow lite documentation and examples about this
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/task_library/overview
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples

Comment: Did you find any solutions?

Comment: Hi! Have you checked these threads yet?   https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples/text_classification/overview   https://colab.research.google.com/github/sayakpaul/Adventures-in-TensorFlow-Lite/blob/master/EAST_TFLite.ipynb      https://colab.research.google.com/github/tulasiram58827/ocr_tflite/blob/main/colabs/KERAS_OCR_TFLITE.ipynb